# import comma delimited text file with key value pairs into R as a dataframe

Tags: r

I was not able to find answers to this exact scenario.

I have a comma deliminated TXT file where the column names and values are separated by columns. I would like to import it into R as a dataframe. A simple read.table() does not work because of the key: value pair issue. would appreciate any insight you might have

TXT FILE

```
{"Hypertension":false,"lave_mains_avec4":false,"SignatureStatus":"Signature on file","sexe":1,"NomFamilleContact":"testnumbertwo","hematologique":false}
```

In this TXT file, the first column name is hypertension. The value for the column name hypertension is false. The next column name is lave_mains_avec4, the value for this column in false

Thanks so much

Comment: Check out `jsonlite::read_json(path="path/to/your/file.json")`. Note that depending on how the JSON is nested you may need to further simplify the results. See simplifyVector argument

Answer (score 0):

This format is known as JSON (short for **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation). It is an extremely common and versatile format for exchanging data online. There are multiple R packages for parsing json files, including `jsonlite`:

```r
library(jsonlite)

read_json("myfile.txt") |> as.data.frame()
#>   Hypertension lave_mains_avec4   SignatureStatus sexe NomFamilleContact hematologique
#> 1        FALSE            FALSE Signature on file    1     testnumbertwo         FALSE
```